# insert multiple records asp.net sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

there is a table to store borrowed items called borrowTable, lets say a customer take multiple items, I know how to select and insert a single item but how to select and insert multiple items in a single click?

Comment: Care to show some code? :)

Comment: should provide some code and sample data with table structure..else nobody can help you

Comment: am looking for explanation in order to understand the idea before coding

Comment: read this it will help you http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-multiple-records-rows-to-a-Stored-Procedure-in-SQL-Server-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take all your data in a datatable(We can call 'myTable' here) and you can insert as follows

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES (@Value1, @Value2)"; 
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{  
    int retvalue;
    con.Open();   
    foreach (DataRow row in myTable.Rows)   
    {      
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand();
        myCommand.Connection = con;      
        myCommand.CommandText = sql;      
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", r["Value1"]);      
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2", r["Value2"]);              
        retvalue = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();   
    }
}
```

Comment: In case of SQL server you need to user 'SqlConnection','SqlCommand' instead of  'MySqlConnection' and 'MySqlCommand'

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to copy lots of data from any resources to SQL Server is BulkCopying.

See this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16922/SQL-Bulk-Copy-with-C-Net).